# Unable to autofocus input element in Firefox add-on tab

Tags: html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I used `.open()` to create a tab displaying the HTML in `data/search.html` and attached `data/search.js` as a content script file.

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

function executeSearch () {
 /* set up search tab */
 tabs.open({
   url: data.url("search.html"),
   onReady: function (tab) {
    var worker = tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: data.url("search.js")
    });
    worker.port.on("searchtext", function (wordsJson) {
      worker.port.emit("matchingPages", JSON.stringify(hlutils.matchingPages(wordsJson)));
    });
   }
 });
}
```

The HTML displays correctly and the content script runs properly, but in the HTML file (which is in valid HTML5) the `autofocus` property of an input element is not honored.  Basically there is no cursor in the page as displayed, and no input can be made without clicking into the input element.  I tried doing it the old-fashioned way by using

```
document.getElementById("search").focus();
```

in the content script file, and also in a `script` element in the HTML file (below the referenced element), all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  Had to add the following to the content script file:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  document.getElementById("search").focus();
});
```